# Docker EROFS: read-only file system, unlink webpack-dev-server

Tags: docker, webpack, node-modules

Some of my docker containers don't want to be up.
when I run `sudo docker-compose up`

I get this error :

- client_1   | EROFS: read-only file system, unlink '/usr/src/client/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/ssl/server.pem'

- client_1   | error Command failed with exit code 1.*

I tried to insert `"dependenciesMeta": {"webpack-dev-server": {"unplugged": true}}`  in my package.json but nothing has changed.

I've also tried to add to my Package.json `"engines": {"yarn": "x.x"},`

Comment: What's in your `docker-compose.yml` file?  Your image's Dockerfile(s)?  Can you provide  a [mcve] that explains what's leading up to this error?